# Swiftui avplayer handle stop video

Tags: swift, swiftui

i am making avplayer with swiftui. With uiviewcontrollerrepresenta what I need is whether the video being played is finished or not, if it is done I need to take action accordingly.

```
struct VideoPlayerSwiftUI : UIViewControllerRepresentable {
var playerURL : String
@State var status : AVPlayer.Status
var videoGravity : AVLayerVideoGravity
let avPlayerController = AVPlayerViewController()

func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> AVPlayerViewController   {
    let player = AVPlayer(url: URL(string: playerURL)!)
    avPlayerController.player = player
    avPlayerController.showsPlaybackControls = false
    avPlayerController.player?.play()
    avPlayerController.player?.actionAtItemEnd = .pause
    avPlayerController.videoGravity = videoGravity
    self.addPeriodicTimeObserver()

    return avPlayerController
}

func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: AVPlayerViewController, context: Context) {
}
```

}

Comment: Hey, please consider adding some code to your question so that we can see what you have done and help you accordingly!

Comment: @Marybnq edited